# Filling rectilinear polygon (with holes) with rectangles

Tags: algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm, np

I read that it is NP problem.

But I don't need the smallest number of rectangles.
Just "more or less" good algorithm.

So, the problem.

I have a binary pixel matrix, similar to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#mediaviewer/File%3aScreenshot-Pixel_Region_%28Figure_1%29.png

I need to fill 1's. I can't draw pixel by pixel.
What I planned to do is to cover region with rectangles and fill rectangles.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is polynomial in 2D case, but NP-complete in 3D. It is shown in this [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=110968).

Idea of algorithm, for 2D case, is to reduce problem to maximum matching of bipartite graph (vertices are possible cuts.) Take a look on this [page](http://nanoexplanations.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/polygon-rectangulation-part-1-minimum-number-of-rectangles/) or this [presentation](http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-dstolee1/Presentations/Sto08-MinRectPart.pdf).